# Evaluate $|z|$'s maximum and minimum value under condition:$ \begin{cases} x^2+9y^2-2z^2=0 \\ x+3y+3z=5\\ \end{cases} $

Tags: multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

$$  \begin{cases} 
x^2+9y^2-2z^2=0,(1) \\ 
 x+3y+3z=5,   (2)\\ 
\end{cases} $$

I try to solve maximum and minimum value of $z^2$, maybe Lagrange Multiplier is useful but I can't formulate the equation properly.

From $(1)$ and $(2)$ I can get 
$$g(x,y)=7x^2+20x+63y^2-12xy+60y=0$$
So my Lagrange multiplier is 
$$F(x,y,\lambda)=\frac{x^2+9y^2}{2}+\lambda g(x,y)$$
But I can't solve the following equation
$$  \begin{cases} 
F'_x=0 \\ 
 F'_y=0\\ 
F'_{\lambda}=0\\
\end{cases} $$
So I think there must be something wrong with my method. Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: The first two equations $F'_x = 0, F'_y= 0$ are a linear system with a parameter ($\lambda$). Consider the possible cases (compatible, determined...).

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla The first two equation give me$x(10-2x)=y(30-18y)$, and $F'_{lambda}=7x^2+20x+63y^2-12xy+60y=0$. I stuck here. And what is determined?

Comment: The first two equations $F′_x=0,F′_y=0$ *have* a unique solution for *almost all* $\lambda$.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla As is shown in Gyumin's answer, there are at least two solutions. which is $x=1$ and $x=-5$.

Comment: I'm not talking about the *original* system, **but** about $F_x'=0, F_y'=0$. And the *almost all* $\lambda$ is important.

Comment: And the most natural solution for this problem with *two* restrictions is using *two* multipliers.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla Actually, I didn't know that I can use two restrictions. I'll visit related  Wikipedia pages. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Cauchy-Schwarz, we have $$4z^2=(1+1)(x^2+9y^2) \ge (x+3y)^2 = (5-3z)^2$$ giving $$(z-1)(z-5) \le 0$$ which implies $$1 \le z \le 5$$ $$1 \le z^2 \le 25$$

The equality holds at $(x,y,z)=(1,\frac{1}{3},1)$ and $(x,y,z)=(-5,-\frac{5}{3},5)$

Comment: Wow! Really nice answer. And are there any general/analytical methods,  just tell me ideas, I can do the calculation myself.

Comment: Set $x=5-3y-3z$ and plug it into the first equation. Then, we have $18y^2+(18z-30)y+7z^2-30z+25=0$. Then find the discriminant, which turns out to be $-180(z^2-6z+5)$. The solution follows.

Answer (score 1):

One thing we need to realize is $z^2$ is maximized when $h(x,y,z)=z$ is either maximized or minimized.

By taking the partial derivatives with respect to $x,y,z$, you have

$$2x\lambda+u=0\implies x=-{u\over2\lambda}$$
$$18y\lambda+3u=0\implies y=-{u\over6\lambda}$$
$$-4z\lambda+3u+v=0\implies z={3u+v\over4\lambda}$$

Now sub in to $x+3y+3z=5$ and $x^2+9y^2-2z^2=0$, let ${u\over\lambda}=a$ and ${v\over\lambda}=b$ you get

$$-{1\over2}a-{1\over2}a+{9\over4}a+{3\over4}b=5\implies 5a+3b=20$$

$${1\over4}a^2+{1\over4}a^2-{1\over8}(3a+b)^2=0\implies 4a^2=(3a+b)^2$$

(1) $2a=3a+b$, we have $a=10,b=-10\implies z=5$

(2) $2a=-3a-b$, we have $a=-2,b=10\implies z=1$

Hence $z$ is maximized at $5$ and minimized at $1$ and $z^2$ is maximized at $25$.

Comment: What are $u$ and $v$ here? I don't quite understand

Comment: When we are dealing with multiple equations, we use multiple lagrange multipliers, here we have three equations $f(x,y,z)=x^2+9y^2-2z^2,g(x.y.z)=x+3y+3z,h(x,y,z)=z$ so we want three multipliers such that $\lambda f'+ug'+vh'=0$.

Comment: Two multipliers are enough because we have two *restrictions*. Also, the (possible) case $z=0$ gives a minimum of $z^2$ even if isn't  an extreme of $z$.

Comment: That's correct in theory we can use a and b from beginning but making a linear combination form looks better imo. z=0 is not possible since x and y has to be 0 as well and the second equation cannot be satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: the linear system
$$\eqalign{
\lambda(- 12 y + 2 x + 20) = F_x' &= 0 \cr
\lambda(126 y - 12 x + 60) + 9 =F_y'&= 0\cr
}$$
has a unique solution for $12\lambda^2 + 16\lambda + 1\ne 0$ (why?).

What happens when $12\lambda^2 + 16\lambda + 1 = 0$?